# Testing a JSON appender in Spring Boot fails when running multiple tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, logstash-logback-encoder

In a Spring Boot application I'm using the following logback configuration in `logback-spring.xml`.

Depending on the Spring property `app.json-logging` the application shall either use the default `CONSOLE` appender or the custom `CONSOLE_JSON` appender which writes log messages in JSON.

While the configuration is working, I'm having trouble writing a test for this behavior. Please see the below test class.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <!-- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging.logback -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="jsonLogging" source="app.json-logging"/>
  
    <appender name="CONSOLE_JSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <if condition='property("jsonLogging").equals("true")'>
            <then>
                <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_JSON"/>
            </then>
            <else>
                <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
                <appender-ref ref="GELF"/>
            </else>
        </if>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

The test class...

```java
@ActiveProfiles("json-logging")
public class LoggingIT extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    private final PrintStream originalSystemOut = System.out;
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream logCapturingStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(logCapturingStream));
    }

    @AfterEach
    void afterEach() {
        System.setOut(originalSystemOut);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldLogMessagesInJsonFormat() throws JSONException {
        final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingIT.class);

        logger.info("Test log message");

        String capturedLog = logCapturingStream.toString();
        final JSONObject jsonLog = new JSONObject(capturedLog);

        assertThat(jsonLog.get("message").toString()).isEqualTo("Test log message");
    }
}
```

The test passes when running it on its own. It fails, however, when running it along with the other integration tests, e.g. in `mvn verify`. The assertion fails because the test then does not use `CONSOLE_JSON` but `CONSOLE`, so it seems as if the logger is not "re-initialized" for this test class.

I already tried adding `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_CLASS)` but it does not work either.